# R.java file is not generated in a library project

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm trying to use the **[SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)** library. As described, I created a new Android project using the **library** directory, tried "Project > Clean" to generate the R.java but doesn't work.

The curious fact is that if I open the project properties and uncheck the "Is Library" all will work and R.java file is generated without errors. Besides the errors with the lack of R.java file, the tab "Problems" presents this:

> Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output.

If I remove, as suggested in several responses, it appears again when I clean the project.

I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: project -- > build automatically , check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I do not know exactly what the reason, but the solution was to remove the Eclipse, the Android SDK and use the **ADT Bundle** from this link: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Before I was using a standard Eclipse IDE with the ADT plugin.

Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 2):

Un-checking and re-checking and "**is library**" helped for me.

Under Preferences > Android (for that lib project)

Answer (score 1):

There are many thing to get back R.java

1. clean project
2. Build project from project
3. change the api of ex 2.2 to 4.0 and 4.0 to other version it will (re)create R.java file

**finaly yet** you cannot able to get R.java file then copy R.java file from other project paste it into gen folder then just build project.

Comment: Glad to see that you can use html tags, but please try to use the normal formatting options for the next time. Also: The last tip to copy the R-File is plain stupid. Each build will start with a remove of the R.java file to generate it again... so copying it will help, not...

Comment: @WarrenFaith always i am using that way to copy r file becuase when i change api it will remove r file in some case so i clean project if i got r file then fine otherwise i copy r file from other project build project and then all id store in r file and use it.

Comment: If the R file is removed, you have some problem in your xml files. Copying the R file is a possible work around but will not solve any real issues in your project...

Answer (score 0):

> eclipse -> project -> build automatically -> check it

If it is already checked, uncheck it and check it again.